# How do I use conditions in my ggvis code?

Tags: r, shiny, conditional-statements, ggvis

I have a dataframe with different columns that I want to plot, but I have created a checkbox in Shiny to indicate which ones I want to plot.

UI.R

```
tabPanel('Data Insights',
           mainPanel(
                      ggvisOutput("plot4"),
                      fluidRow(
                               checkboxGroupInput('investcheck', 'Investment', 
                                              choices = c('OOH', 'PRINT', 'TV', 'DIGITAL'), 
                                              selected=c('TV')))             
           )
  )
```

SERVER.R

```
reactive({
    if(is.element('PRINT', input$investcheck)) {oprint=1} else {oprint=0}
    if(is.element('OOH', input$investcheck)) {oooh=1} else {oooh=0}
    if(is.element('TV', input$investcheck)) {otv=1} else {otv=0}
    if(is.element('DIGITAL', input$investcheck)) {odigital=1} else {odigital=0}

    plt <- df_sales %>% ggvis(~sales) %>%
    if(oprint==1) {
      plt <- plt %>%
      layer_points(data = df_sales, x = ~sales, y = ~PRINT_Investment, fill:='3498DB')
    } else{
      plt <- plt %>%
        layer_points(data = df_sales, x = ~sales, y = ~PRINT_Investment, fill:='3498DB')
    }
    plt

  }) %>% bind_shiny("plot4")
```

But I always have an error:

```
Warning in if (.) oprint == 1 else { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
Error in if (.) oprint == 1 else { : 
  argument is not interpretable as logical
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally correct it! It was an extra '%>%' and I changed my code:

## SERVER.R

```
  reactive({

    
    plt <- df_sales %>% ggvis(~sales)
    if('PRINT' %in% input$investcheck) {
      plt <- plt %>%
      layer_points(data = df_sales, x = ~sales, y = ~PRINT_Investment, fill:='3498DB')
    }
    if('TV' %in% input$investcheck) {
      plt <- plt %>%
        layer_points(data = df_sales, x = ~sales, y = ~TV_Investment, fill:='1ABC9C')
    }
    if('OOH' %in% input$investcheck) {
      plt <- plt %>%
        layer_points(data = df_sales, x = ~sales, y = ~OOH_Investment, fill:='F39C12')
    }
    if('DIGITAL' %in% input$investcheck) {
      plt <- plt %>%
        layer_points(data = df_sales, x = ~sales, y = ~DIGITAL_Investment, fill:='E74C3C')
    }
    
    plt
    
  }) %>% bind_shiny("plot4")
```